# Doctrine migration ignores @Table Annotation in @Entity definition

Tags: symfony, orm, annotations, doctrine

I have the following Doctrine Entity in Symfony 4.2:

When I run the migration the unique constraints and the indexes are not generated. The result of the Entity are just the following indexes in MySql:

- PRIMARY (id)
- identifier (identifier), Unique

#### Media.php

```
<?php 
// src/Entity/Media.php
namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\UniqueConstraint;

/**
 * Common\Model\Entity\Media
 *
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="media", 
 *    uniqueConstraints={
 *        @UniqueConstraint(name="virtual_unique", 
 *            columns={"virtualname", "virtualfolder"})
 *    }
 *    indexes={
 *        @Index(name="idx_virtual", columns={"virtualname", "virtualfolder"})
 *        @Index(name="idx_identifier", columns={"identifier"}) 
 *    }
 * )
 */

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\MediaRepository")
 */
class Media
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true, options={"unique": true})
     */
    private $identifier;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    private $virtualname;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $virtualfolder;
}
```

Comment: Are you using Doctrine Migrations? What does the migration itself look like? Does Doctrine recognize the missing indizes when doing `bin/console doctrine:schema:validate`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have multiple annotation blocks for the same class. Just merge them and have a single annotation block for that entity.

And you are using serveral annotations  directly, **but not importing their definitions**. Specifically:

- `@Entity`
- `@Index`
- `@UniqueConstraint`
- `@Table`

Either you:

#### Use them prefixed by `@ORM`(since you are doing `use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM`)

This is the most convenient and the one that's usually applied.

A complete fix:

```php
/**
 * Common\Model\Entity\Media
 *
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\MediaRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="media", 
 *    uniqueConstraints={
 *        @ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="virtual_unique", 
 *            columns={"virtualname", "virtualfolder"})
 *    },
 *    indexes={
 *        @ORM\Index(name="idx_virtual", columns={"virtualname", "virtualfolder"}),
 *        @ORM\Index(name="idx_identifier", columns={"identifier"}) 
 *    }
 * )
 */
class Media
{}
```

#### Or, you use the full namespace declaration in those annotations

You could also use the annotations with the full namespace, like `@Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Table`, `@Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\UniqueConstraint`, etc; but that gets unnecessarily verbose very quickly.

#### Or, you could import each of the annotations independently

```php
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Table;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Index;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\UniqueConstraint;
```

But it also seems wasteful.

---

The approach you'll see on the docs is the first one. Import `Doctrine\ORM\Mapping` as `ORM`, and use the annotations hanging from there.

Comment: if I run "php bin/console doctrine:schema:validate" I get the following error: [Syntax Error] Expected Doctrine\Common\Annotations\DocLexer::T_CLOSE_PARENTHESIS, got 'indexes' at position 241 in class App\Entity\Media.
I am 100% sure that the paranthesis are correcty stacked into each other

Comment: @Gerfried I think there is a missing comma (`,`) just before `indexes`.

Comment: thanks, and another one between the two index definitions ;-)

Comment: Indeed. I had just copied your code and didn't fully check those details, since they were kinda out-of-scope for your question. Thanks for the heads up, I'll amend my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you need change `@Table` to `@ORM\Table` and remove `@Entity`

try this:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\MediaRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="media", 
 *    uniqueConstraints={
 *        @UniqueConstraint(name="virtual_unique", 
 *            columns={"virtualname", "virtualfolder"})
 *    }
 *    indexes={
 *        @ORM\Index(name="idx_virtual", columns={"virtualname", "virtualfolder"})
 *        @ORM\Index(name="idx_identifier", columns={"identifier"}) 
 *    }
 * )
 */
```

Comment: Good catch. It looks like `@Index` requires the `ORM`-Prefix as well, `@ORM\Index`.

Answer (score -1):

#### Clearing my cache did the trick for me.

I tried a few other suggestions, but after a `cache:clear` I got the index in my migration.